# XAMPP - Does not load latest changes to Style Sheet

Tags: css, xampp

I'm building a website which I am using XAMPP to test. I am really struggling with the design because whenever I have refreshed the localhost webpage in the browser, the design changes do not seem to have been applied. Last time I finished implementing, I closed XAMPP and my HTML/CSS editor, and when I've opened them and loaded the page again, some of the changes that had previously not been applied were now applied to the page.
I tried to change these values again and refresh the page, to see if it was finally working as expected, and the latest changes failed to apply again.

I have literally no idea what is going on, but it would seem that the changes can only be applied when XAMPP is newly started and the page is loaded for the first time. Can anyone suggest why this might be?

Thanks in advance,

Mark

Comment: Tried crtl+f5 to reload the page?

Comment: Kind of off-topic. But you should search for "disable xampp cache" or "php css timestamp" etc.

Comment: You could try a cache busting technique where you include your CSS file. Add a `?v=<some numbers>` at the end of your CSS file's location. Something like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=e031e80c3d8b">`.

Comment: That has got it, I'm new to web design so wasn't even aware of this technique. Thank you. @seahorsepip

Answer (score 4):

You could try a cache busting technique where you include your CSS file. Add a `?v=<some numbers>` at the end of your CSS file's location.

Something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=e031e80c3d8b">
```

You could use PHP's [time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function to generate the hash for you. As it's a Unix timestamp it will change each time you refresh.

```php
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">
```

Though I wouldn't consider this a long term solution. Without additional info it's hard to make any possible XAMPP related suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments this may be a cache problem. You can use this simple PHP code to add timestamp version automatically without having to set numbers each time you make an update:

**Define the timestamp variable**

```
<?php
$timestamp = date("YmdHis"); // output: 20150715164614
?>
```

**Add timestamp to files**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css?v=<?php echo $timestamp;?>">
```

---

Alternatively, you can **disable caching** altogether by sending these PHP headers

```
header('Expires: Sun, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Answer (score 1):

quite an annoying little problem with numerous threads with suggestions for solutions/workaround. Emptying the browser cache (Safari) worked for a while for me but simply restarting the Apache servers from the Xampp manager after making the CSS stylesheet changes seemed to work best. I repeated a couple of times to test and after It even seemed to get the developer tools window to work on the fly consistently which it was not doing in XAMPP at all prior. Hard refresh appeared to have no effect interestingly, hope it helps!

Comment: I've come across this issue sporadically since posting the above answer. Most consistent solutions are probably adding the timestamp as suggested by hungerstar above and using the Network tab in developer console to hard refresh +- clear cache on the specific page as suggested by Dan Brown below.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue too and I'm posting this answer as soon as I found the solution. Having read this thread before (thanks to the earlier answers provided), I knew it had something to do with the cache. Glad I found it now

Access your Developers tools through Inspect and select the Network menu toolbar above. Next, click on Disable cache and reload your webpage.. TADA!!!

Unfortunately, it seems I cannot post images

Comment: Once you gain more reputation you will be able to.

Comment: You could have given a bit more detail for those not familiar with Network tab in the develop console which is super useful. Click and hold down the circular refresh arrow in the web address bar while the Network tab is open which brings up the option to hard refresh +/- clear cache which both should work.

Answer (score -1):

rename the folder and change path in your css file

Comment: Hello! This would be a more helpful answer if you explained **why** changing the path to the CSS file displays recent changes.